# Leafletjs Custom Coord

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to get a leaflet set up for a service I'm creating, but I can't seem to get the alignment set up correctly. The marker on the bottom is at the correct location, however, the top, and far-right marker are not in their correct positions, as noted with the X's on the map: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q94ar.jpg

This is the image I'm currently using, apologies, it's massive at the moment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jwkaJ2RWhB6QnUjKCIaJ2Ex0Hc7JE45p/view

This is my current code:

```js
var bottomLeft = [-4533, -3681];
var topRight = [7467, 4319];

var factor = 1 / 16;

myCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(factor, 0, -factor, 0)
});

GTAMap = L.map('map-canvas', {
  crs: myCRS,
  minZoom: -4
});

var image = L.imageOverlay('images/tiles/postal/rawGTAMap1.png', bounds).addTo(GTAMap);

GTAMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

I believe my problem is I have the bounds set incorrectly. I have no clue how to do it, but I believe you have to use the bounds to tell leaflet where you want 0, 0 to be centered, which I've done using gimp.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Pixels vs. map units](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html#pixels-vs-map-units)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or a other online version where we can test

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are working with pixel coordinates but leaflet still thinks you're using geographical coordinates. Try adding this at the beginning of your file:

```
var yx = L.latLng;
var xy = function(x, y) {
  if (L.Util.isArray(x)) { // When doing xy([x, y]);
    return yx(x[1], x[0]);
  }
  return yx(y, x); // When doing xy(x, y);
};
```

And then define you're bounds like this:

```
var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(max x value, max y value)];
```

Alternativly, you might want to [have a look here](https://fictionalmaps.com/).

Comment: This is not correct what are you saying! Leaflet is not "thinking" in `geographical coordinates` when you using `L.CRS.Simple`, it thinks in `map units` [Doc](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html#common-gotchas-in-crssimple-maps). The function what are you posted is only to make it more readable and understandable to use [x,y], because by default Leaflet is using [y,x]

Comment: That's why I started with "I think" ;-) I'm no expert by far. But I just noticed that layer 8 defines his custom CRS but still adds CRS.Simple instead of myCRS to the map. I'm also not sure if the bounds array is defined correctly, the above code seems incomplete to me.

Comment: myCRS was used as well. I had forgotten to replace that in the code, during my attempts at fixing my problem. I've edited the post now.

Comment: As mentioned above, I'd try and define the bounds by setting 0,0 as the first value in your bounds and the max pixels of the image as the second value - ignoring any map units or such. Not sure where you get the [-4533, -3681] and [7467, 4319] from. If you can't get it to work, there's always sites like the one I linked, where you can just upload and share it as a leaflet map and the rest is taken care of.

Comment: Sadly, that site won't work for me as I need to be able to dynamically add more markers from external sources. I did try setting the bounds that way, but it made the problem worse. The bounds are, to my knowledge, used to tell leaflet where [0,0] should be.